How to block a widgets on blogger
How can i block this url from loading in my blogger website:
https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3298326339-widgets.js
i tried a lot of things like  a added a script to block the url but it does not worked
//<![CDATA[
  (function() {
    var scriptToBlock = 'https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3298326339-widgets.js';
    var allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    
    for (var i = allScripts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var src = allScripts[i].getAttribute('src');
      if (src && src === scriptToBlock) {
        allScripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(allScripts[i]);
        break; // Exit loop after removing the script
      }
    }
  })();
//]]>
</script>


Yes, you can. Set b:js="false" attribute to your HMTL, for example:
<html b:js="false">
...
</html>

But, this method will make your Contact Form widget stopped working.
